# Traduction de « moi-léger » ?

Tags: traduction, paroles-de-chanson

Dans la chanson « Moi-léger » de Karkwa il y a les paroles :

> C’est un passage obligé
>
> Un long couloir à creuser
>
> Entre moi et moi-léger

Je ne comprends pas trop ce que ça veut dire ou voudrait dire dans une traduction en anglais. Quelqu’un a des idées ?

Answer (score 1):

Je ne comprends pas non plus ce que ça signifie précisément en français.

Peut-être que ***moi*** représente la personne physique et ***moi-léger*** son esprit, son âme...

Answer (score 1):

I can't read perfect consistency in that poetic song and it might be missing; however, there seems to be an unavoidable line of thinking leading to a sastisfying idea; it might constitute a capital interpretation.

*Here are the lyrics*

Y avait l'hiver, y avait le froid qui me tuait
Mais là c'est pu important
Y avait le temps, y avait les âges qui défilaient
Mais là je m'en fous vraiment

C'est un passage obligé
Un long couloir à creuser
Entre moi et moi-léger
C'est une chanson de lumière
L'étape après la misère
L'émotion d'un courant d'air

Y avait les filles, y avait le rock qui nous saoulait
Mais là c'est pu important
Y avait les routes, y avait les trous que l'on grugeait
Mais c'est de moins en moins pesant

C'est un passage obligé
Un long couloir à creuser
Entre moi et moi-léger
C'est comme un nouveau printemps
Un plongeon dans l'océan
C'est comme le vin dans le sang

Y avait la guerre, y avait les droits qui nous mentaient
Mais là c'est moins prenant
Y avait le ciel, y avait les dieux qui me hantaient
Mais là je m'en fous vraiment

C'est une chanson de lumière
L'étape après la misère
L'émotion d'un courant d'air

*What might be understood*

What « ce » stands for in the past life: past hardships (winter, poverty (misère), guerre, oppression (droits qui mentaient), lack of sedentarity (les routes))

What "ce" is now: fate (passage obligé),  experience to reflect upon (couloir à creuser (ambiguity: life past in which to strive (creuser)/memories to analyse now (creuser)), the emphasis on how preferable is the new life (nouveau printemps, vin dans le sang: tipsiness, relief from not being under the yoke anymore, relief from pressure from above (ciel, dieux)).

One possible conclusion is that "son moi" is his whole soul "son moi-léger" is his new psychological make-up due to the change of life; it is light because freed from the yoke, because  the life past is not weighing him down, as that could possibly have been the case. Then this past life is the explanation to his "nouveau moi", the "moi-léger", a passage from what he is as a whole to what he is now.

*A tentative translation*

It's fateful hardship
a link and its food for thought
from myself to myself reborn.

Answer (score 1):

Tout comme @jilliagre je ne comprends pas le sens de cette phrase, j'aurais tendance à prendre en considération le fait que l'on s'allège (l'esprit) lorsque l'on se confesse, lorsque l'on s'excuse par exemple.

Dans ce cas le moi-léger pourrait être ma propre personne vidée de ses mensonges / péchés, néanmoins ce n'est qu'une supposition, je ne connais pas le contexte.